# how to reprogram an old computer rom and use it as rom memory for another task?

Tags: microcontroller, robotics, rom

I've ripped open an old Pentium desktop. The main board is a Zida 5svx. I got to know from the manual (which i downloaded from the internet) the location of the ROM chip on the board, and took it out. It was mentioned in the manual that the chip was a Flash EEPROM.

Now, what I am interested in is this: Is there a way to erase the ROM and flash it with, say a C program to blink an LED (i know this might put you into a fit of laughter, but read on all the same), or control a motor?

I also want to know if I can construct a mega-sized micro-controller with the left-over Pentium, some MBs of RAM, and this ROM.

Any suggestions?

P.S: I know that such a uC will require appropriate power supply setup and things.

Comment: the short answer is yes this is all quite possible.  HOW?  that is the question, and it varies from motherboard to motherboard.  there may be things like dram that you may lose by not using the vendors prom.  If instead you allow the bios to work and boot normally (if the board works well enough) then you can use some flavor of boot device (floppy, hard disk, one of the many flash based ide disk like devices, cdrom, etc) to boot your own blink an led program.  to blink the led though requires knowledge of the board layout if there are any leds.

Comment: Thanks dwelch... But i was looking for, like seperating the board into its individual components, and then putting them together like i want to... Any ideas or suggested resources? Thanks in advance...

Comment: not understanding, you want to pull the processor off and put on a new, made by you, board?  there is a lot more to that, very doable, but it is going to cost you some bucks, is that what you are really after?

Comment: the part number of the processor should lead you to the right docs at intel which will tell you what you need to feed the processor to make it work, various voltages with the right startup sequence and tolerances, clock or clocks, bus interface timing, etc.

Comment: Thanks dwelch. I think that ought to open some doors...

Answer (score 0):

The key is in getting and deeply studying the manufacturer's datasheets for each device you remove and wish to reuse.  I am supposing that since you asked the question that you did that you are not a professional electrical engineer - that's OK, but you will need to do hours, days, or weeks of study to truly understand the datasheets well enough to successfully reuse your motherboard chips because they are written for professional engineers with years of experience, and unfortunately they were not written to be understood by hobbyists.  If you can succeed in acquiring and thoroughly understanding all of the datasheets (and the related user's guides as well for the more complex chips) then you have made it to the point where you might be able to start a custom design based on your recovered parts, on paper at least.  In order to test your design and insure that each part of it is working will require at least an oscilloscope and volt meter - and the knowledge of how to use them.  An understanding of basic electronics is essential, you will not succeed without it.  Very good soldering/rework/assembly skills will be required as well if you hope to have your design truly work - you can do everything else right and it can still fail if your skills in this area are lacking.  There is simply not enough time for me to advise you on everything you will need to know - but if you are motivated, dedicated, and you don't give up when setbacks and roadblocks occur (and trust me, they occur all too frequently for even the best engineers and best designs) - meaning that you are not easily frustrated when things don't work - then you have a chance at success.  I wish you all the best, and try to have fun while doing it (important in case fun is all you ever get out of your project).  :)